# How to get an HTML button disabled status (true or false) into AppleScript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, applescript

Buttons in webpages have a disabled status. This status can be true or false. if true, that means the button is greyed out on the webpage.

With Javascript, I can retrieve the status with this:

```
document.getElementById('view-more').disabled
```

it will either return true or false.

But if I combine this with AppleScript:

```
set buttonStatus to do Javascript "document.getElementById('view-more').disabled
```

Nothing gets returned about the status of the button.

The actual HTML code for the button is:

```
<button id="view-more" class="view_more">View more</button>
```

And when the button is disabled it becomes:

```
<button id="view-more" class="view_more" disabled="disabled">View more</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple **HTML** *file* with a disabled *button*, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('button').disabled;" in document 1
end tell
```

---

The contents of the **HTML** *file* as shown in **Terminal**:

```html
% cat button.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="button" disabled>Button</button>
  </body>
</html>
%
```

Screen Shot of **Script Editor**:

[image]

---

With the *button* enabled.

The contents of the **HTML** *file* as shown in **Terminal**:

```html
% cat button.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="button">Button</button>
  </body>
</html>
%
```

Screen Shot of **Script Editor**:

[image]

Comment: I tried running your code with the same html button code you provided, but my system (M1 MacBook Air) would not return a true or false in AppleScript. I tried running your AppleScript code in both Script Editor and Script Debugger. The actual HTML code for the button in non-disabled status is <button id="view-more" class="view_more">View more</button> and the code for the button when disabled is <button id="view-more" class="view_more" disabled="disabled">View more</button>

Comment: It looks like the code you provided works correctly on your system, but not mine.

Comment: @Wayland Chin, With the _example_ **HTML** _file_ loaded in **Safari** under **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur** the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ in my answer does indeed work as indicated by the screen shots. Using the **HTML** _code_ provided in your comment and making appropriate changes to the **AppleScript** _code_ to use it, it too works on two different systems I tested it on.

Comment: @Wayland Chin, In **Safari** do you have **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** checked on the **Safari** > **Develop** menu?  --  Note it is hidden by default and can be shown by checking **[√] Show Develop menu in menu bar** in: **Safari** > **Preferences…** > **Advanced**

Comment: I do have 'Allow JavaScript from Apple Events' checked in the Develop menu. This is strange. How can the exact same code have a return value for your computer, but not mine? Thanks for your help in investigating this. It is much appreciated.

Comment: @Wayland Chin, Is the _web page_ the _button_ is on reachable by anyone? If yes, then please provide the **URL**, otherwise there is not much more I can do unless you can post the _source code_ of the _web page_ to e.g. [https://paste.ee](https://paste.ee) or similar.

Comment: The webpage requires a username and password, but I extracted the exact code for the button from the web page. It looks like this `<button id="view-more" class="view_more" disabled="disabled">View more</button>`